# Laplace transform of derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, laplace-transform

In an example in the book we are given the following ODE: $x''-x'-6x=0$. In addition we are given the following definitions:

$L{f'(t)}=sF(s)-f(0)$ and

$L{f''}=s^2-sf(0)-f'(0)$

The part I am confused about is what is the transformation of $-6x$? I don't see one laid out in the text.

Comment: $L(-6x)=-6X(s)$ simply  or $-6F(s)$ with your notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x''-x'-6x=0$$
Apply the Laplace Transform:
$$\mathcal {L}(x''-x'-6x)=0$$
$$\mathcal {L}(x'')-\mathcal {L}(x')-\mathcal {L}(6x)=0$$
Since you have that:
$L[6x](s)=6\int_0^\infty e^{-ts}\,x(t)\,dt =6X(s)$
Hence:
$$\mathcal {L}(x'')-\mathcal {L}(x')-6X(s)=0$$
You know what to do with the first two terms.
$$\mathcal {L}{(x'')}=s^2X(s)-sx(0)-x'(0)$$
$$\mathcal {L}{(x')}=sX(s)-x(0)$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition,
\begin{align}
L[6x](s)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-ts}\,6t\,dt \\
&\stackrel{IBP}{=}\left[-\frac{1}{s}e^{-ts}6t\right]_{t=0}^\infty + \frac{6}{s}\int_0^\infty e^{-ts}\,dt
\end{align}